# Docker Desktop is not running

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to run Web app from visualStudio2019 and get the following error in the 'Docker Tools' output:

> ========== Checking for Container Prerequisites ==========
>
> Verifying that Docker Desktop is installed...
>
> Docker Desktop is installed.
>
> ========== Verifying that Docker Desktop is running... ==========
>
> Verifying that Docker Desktop is running...
>
> Starting Docker Desktop...
>
> Visual Studio container tools require Docker to be running. Docker
> Desktop is not running.
>
> ========== Finished ==========

Docker Destop do run on my computer. How can I fix that

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by openning PowerShell as administrator and running the following:

> cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"

> ./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon

I also checked with

> docker run hello-world